# Finding vector of co-ordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do we find a co-ordinate vector in Algebra?

For example, given:

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & -3 \\ 
0  & -4
\end{matrix}\right) & \left(\begin{matrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{matrix}\right) = 0
\end{align*}
$$

How do we calculate $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices? Do you know what it means to say two matrices are equal? Furthermore do you understand that the RHS is actually short for  $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & -3 \\ 
0  & -4
\end{matrix}\right) & \left(\begin{matrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{matrix}\right) = 0
\end{align*}\Rightarrow 
$$
$$\begin{align*}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2v_1-3v_2 \\0v_1-4v_2
\end{matrix}
\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align*}\Rightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases}2v_1-3v_2=0\\-4v_2=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases}v_1=0\\v_2=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

### The hard way

Whenever you have a linear system of the form:
$$A\vec x = \vec b$$
where $A$ is a square matrix and $\vec x$ and $\vec b$ are column vectors, you can solve this by finding $A^{-1}$:
$$\vec x = A^{-1}\vec b$$
To find $A^{-1}$, we augment $A$ with the identity, and row reduce.

So, for your example:
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 2 & -3 \\ 0 & -4
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\vec{b} = \vec 0$$
$$\vec{x} = \binom{v_1}{v_2}$$
So, to find $A^{-1}$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
2 & -3  & 1 & 0\\
0 & -4  & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
\implies \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
2 & -3  & 1 & 0\\
0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4}\end{array}\right)
\implies\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0  & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{-3}{8}\\
0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4}\end{array}\right)$$
So, $A^{-1} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-3}{8}\\ 0 & \frac{-1}{4}}$.

Now, we simply plug into our formula:
$$\pmatrix{v_1 \\v_2} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-3}{8}\\ 0 & \frac{-1}{4}}\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$$

Multiplying matrices, we have:
$$\pmatrix{v_1 \\v_2} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$$

### The easy way

We can also note that this is a homogeneous linear system with linearly independent rows.  We can conclude, therefore, that the only solution of this system is the trivial one; that is, $v_1 = 0, v_2 = 0$.